# Promesas en servicio angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http

estoy intentando ahora mismo hacer una llamada a un servidor con http y continuar con la ejecución cuando la llamada haya terminado y para ello estoy intentando usar las promesas, pero no consigo que el programa espere a la respuesta antes de continuar.

app.AppCharacterData.ts (este es el componente desde el que realizo la llamada a la función)

```
public raceSelect(name, route) {
    this.charVar.race = name;
    this.http.getRaceInfo('https://www.dnd5eapi.co'+route).then(console.log(this.charVar.raceInfo));
  }
```

httpGet.service.ts (este es el servicio que procesa la llamada)

```
public getRaceInfo(route) {

    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.http.get(route).subscribe(response => {

              this.charVar.raceInfo = response;

              this.charVar.raceBonuses = this.charVar.raceInfo.ability_bonuses;
              this.charVar.raceAge = this.charVar.raceInfo.age;
              this.charVar.raceAlignment = this.charVar.raceInfo.alignment;
              this.charVar.raceLangDesc = this.charVar.raceInfo.language_desc;
              this.charVar.raceLangs = this.charVar.raceInfo.languages;
              this.charVar.raceSize = this.charVar.raceInfo.size;
              this.charVar.raceSizeDesc = this.charVar.raceInfo.size_description;
              this.charVar.raceSpeed = this.charVar.raceInfo.speed;
              this.charVar.raceProfics = this.charVar.raceInfo.starting_proficiencies;
              this.charVar.raceProficsOpts = this.charVar.raceInfo.starting_proficiency_options;
              this.charVar.raceSubraces = this.charVar.raceInfo.subraces;
              this.charVar.raceTraits = this.charVar.raceInfo.traits;

          }, err => {
              throw err;
          }, () => {
              resolve();
          });
        }
    );

  return promise;

  }
```

En teoría "resolve()" debería ejecutarse cuando la llamada haya terminado, y por lo tanto todos los datos estén ya guardados, pero el .then de raceSelect() sigue sacando por consola un array vacío, al menos la primera vez, la segunda llamada muestra los datos de la primera, lo que me lleva a pensar que la ejecución continúa sin esperar a la promesa, ¿por que puede ser esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La `Promise` que devuelve tu método `getRaceInfo` no se resuelve porque nunca se llama a la función `resolve`.

La tercera *callback* del método `subscribe` de un `Observable<>` es el `onComplete`. `onComplete` va a llamarse cuando se invoca el método `complete` del `Observable<>`, pero la librería `HttpClientModule` de *Angular* no lo hace cuando la petición HTTP va bien (*200 OK*, etc).

### Solución

La solución inmediata es llamar a `resolve` dentro del cuerpo de la primera *callback*.

```
public getRaceInfo(route) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.http.get(route).subscribe(
            response => {
                // ...
                resolve();
            }, err => {
                // En vez de propagar el error
                // rechazamos la Promise<>.
                reject(err);
            });
        }
    );
}
```

La forma más correcta y limpia sería convertir el propio `Observable<>` a `Promise<>` con el método `toPromise()`.

```
public getRaceInfo(route) {
    return this.http.get(route)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => {
                   // ...
               });
    // No hace falta poner el catch explicitamente
    // porque se va a propagar al then de la llamada
    // a getRaceInfo.
    // Si se necesita hacer algo más concreto con ese
    // error, entonces sí.
}
```

Se puede reescribir con `async/await`.

```
public async getRaceInfo(route) {
    const request = this.http.get(route).toPromise();
    const response = await request;

    // ...

    // getRaceInfo devuelve una Promise<void>
    // implícitamente por ser async.
}
```

De nuevo, si se quiere hacer algún tipo de gestión del error habría que contener el cuerpo de `getRaceInfo` en un bloque `try/catch`.

Espero que sirva.